# How to work around missing preprocessing operations in Java's regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, sed

Java does not support preprocessing operations in [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#jcc).  How to work around this missing feature in Java?

I would like to implement a method in Java, which does the same as this [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html) command:

```
$ sed 's/\(^\|_\)\([a-z]\)/\U\2/g' <<< first_name
FirstName
```

The sed call produces camel case.

Comment: Can you describe what that does in English?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think it is obvious that it produces camel case.

Comment: It converts UPPER_CASE into camelCase? It appears to only convert lower_case into camelCase.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No it converts `first_name` into `FirstName`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Sorry but i wrote down the regular expression in order to exactly explain what this call does. I can not see any sense in explaining it in an English approximation.

Comment: I see, it converts lower_case into TitleCase, not camelCase.  "Camel Case" start with an upper or more commonly lower case in programming.

Comment: Because if you can't explain what it does, how is anyone else going to understand what you want it to do. You are using expressions which don't do anything in Java, but you are asking Java people to convert it for you. In Java, while you can use regex it is not a language designed for text processing and often (and in this case) you are better off not using them.

Comment: if you need to preprocess, why don't you do this outside the RegEx with standard string manipulation?

Comment: @PaulBastide Because I like to power of one liners using regular expressions instead of writing a bunch of classes to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(toTitleCase("first_name"));
    System.out.println(toTitleCase("UPPER_CASE"));
    System.out.println(toTitleCase("ßßß_ßßß_ǆǆǆ"));
}

public static String toTitleCase(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : s.split("_+")) {
        sb.append(word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase());
        sb.append(word.substring(1).toLowerCase());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

prints

```
FirstName
UpperCase
SSßßSSßßǄǆǆ
```

Comment: You probably should use `Character.toTitleCase` instead of `toUpperCase` - don't forget that there are characters like ǆ :)

Comment: @Joni Ǆ and ǆ are one letter.

Comment: The title case form of ǆ is ǅ (U+01C5), not Ǆ (U+01C4). There are a few characters that have a distinct upper and title case forms, which is why the whole concept of title case exists in Unicode.

Comment: @ceving I have changed it so it treats __ as _

Comment: @Joni There isn't a title case for String and the title case for ß comes back as ß :|

Comment: True: `java.lang.String` lacks a `toTitleCase` method, there is no public method in `java.lang.Character` that does an expanding case conversion correctly, nor is there any method anywhere else that would do an expanding title case conversion correctly. The people designing the API could have done a better job in this area. But I wouldn't worry much about ß in particular: it's never the first letter of a word, which is why it didn't have an upper case version [until recently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E).

Answer (score 3):

Why not simple use old school string ops?

```
String myStr = "first_name";
myStr = myStr.replace("_", " ");
myStr = StrUtils.Capitalize(myStr);
myStr = mystr.replace(" ", "");
```

StrUtils is from http://commons.apache.org/lang/

If you dont want to add StrUtils, split the Words, and Replace the first character, by simple adding the ASCII difference (32 I think) between the lower case and upper case letters to the char. (Or UpperCase function, etc...)

Comment: Can you try it with `ßßß_ßßß_ǆǆǆ` as the upper case of `ß` is two characters `S` and `S`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Finding a case that does not work is always easy. However its a question if such a case will happen. There are no words starting with `ß` and therefore theres basically no Uppercase `ß`.

Comment: And it does not fit into the context. A word starting with two capital letters does not look like camel case.

Answer (score 0):

I use this now:

```
class camelcase
{
  public static void capitalize (String str, StringBuilder builder)
  {
    int length = str.length();
    if (length > 0) {
      builder.append (Character.toTitleCase(str.charAt(0)));
      if (length > 1)
        builder.append (str.substring(1).toLowerCase());
    }
  }

  public static String capitalize (String str)
  {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    capitalize (str, builder);
    return builder.toString();
  }

  public static void camelcase (String str, StringBuilder builder)
  {
    for (String word : str.split("[ \\p{Punct}]+"))
      capitalize (word, builder);
  }

  public static String camelcase (String str)
  {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    camelcase (str, builder);
    return builder.toString();
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    String[] strings = new String[] {
      "", "a", "aa", "aa_bb", "aa bb", "aa - bb", "ß", "ßß", "ßß_ßß", "ǆǆ"
    };
    for (String str : strings)
      System.out.println ("'" + str + "' -> '" + camelcase (str) + "'");
  }
}
```